# How are tag totals calculated?

Tags: support, tags, site-statistics

I have one non-wiki question with a score of 8 and one non-wiki answer with a score of 4. The display shows 4 tags (x2). Could someone please explain what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean entries like “4 [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) ×2” in [the tags tab in your profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/6635/chetter-hummin?tab=tags)? The tooltip has more details:

> Asked 1 non-wiki questions with a total score of 8.
>   Answered 1 non-wiki questions with a total score of 4.

The number on the left is the total score of your non-wiki answers.

> 2 posts in the star-wars tag

The number on the right is the number of posts, whether questions or answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspected as much but thought that the questions statistics should ideally be displayed separately (if they are being counted) or else displayed in a separate area.